# heightForRowAtIndexPath not called for every cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm implementing a chat functionality in my app, and I'm rolling my own `UIViewController` to do so. I'm using a `UITableView` instead of a `UICollectionView` because it fits my needs better.

Some of my messages are text-based (which can be multi-line) and some of them are image-based. I also have some cells in place to show headers (timestamp information) and footers ("Sending...", "Delivered", etc.).

When I build my data source, I am calculating the height needed for each of these cells, and returning that data in my `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

I am trying to take more control over this process because automatic sizing of cells using auto layout doesn't work all that well when I want the `UITableView` to spend most of its time at the bottom, rather than at the top.

So, I have the following needs:

- When the view loads, it should start fully scrolled to the bottom
- At that point, the `UITableView`'s `contentSize` should be correctly calculated
- Inserting new cells at the bottom of the `UITableView` should work well and also animate well.

The problem I'm finding is that only some of my cells have their height checked by `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

For instance, here's a particular case:

- I have 100 messages + 32 header/footer cells (132 total cells)
- In `viewWillAppear:` (or `viewDidAppear:`, it doesn't seem to matter), I call this:

```
int lastRow           = (int)(self.dataSource.count - 1);
NSIndexPath *lastPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastPath 
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                              animated:animated];
```

It doesn't change much whether the `animated` variable is `YES` or `NO`. `YES` seems to call a few more times, but both of them only really call for values at the top and bottom (beginning/end) of my data source. This means that my calculated content height (which is correct) is not in line with `self.tableView.contentSize.height`.

If, however, I manually scroll up through all of the cells, everything gets sorted out and the `UITableView` is finally aligned with my calculated height.

In addition to the initial view needing to scroll to the bottom, I also want to be able to add new messages to new cells at the bottom of the `UITableView` and then animate them into view. That really doesn't work well if I let the `UITableView` manage its content size and its own animations.

Based on Apple's documentation, I expect it to call `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for every cell. I'm getting that from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview?language=objc):

> There are performance implications to using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of the rowHeight property. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more). See also `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

So, my basic question is how I can force `UITableView` to let me set all of these values. I'm using auto layout within the `UITableViewCell` instances themselves, but I want to have control of cell sizing, rather than letting `UITableView` do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: after inserting a new row to the table . . . call [yourTable reloadData] to get call for the heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1):

Just adding `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0` will solve the problem.